# State-Space-Model from more dimensional Transfer-Function

Tags: control-system, transfer-function, buck-boost, state-space

Im trying to extract the State-Space-Model for an cascaded Buck/Boost-Converter from an set of Transfer-functions \$ G(s)\$ (which I generated with Plecs/Matlab).

[image: Topology]

First of all I want to analyse the Buck-Modus (Sboost=0).

The State-Space-Model should look like this:

\$ \begin{align}
 \dot{\vec{\Delta\mathrm{x}}} 
 = 
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \dot{\Delta \mathrm{uC1}} \\[0.5em]
  \dot{\Delta\mathrm{iL}} \\[0.5em]
  \dot{\Delta\mathrm{uC2}}\\
 \end{bmatrix}
 =
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \mathrm{A_{11}} & \mathrm{A_{12}} & \mathrm{A_{13}} \\[0.5em]
        \mathrm{A_{21}} & \mathrm{A_{22}} & \mathrm{A_{23}} \\[0.5em]
        \mathrm{A_{31}} & \mathrm{A_{32}} & \mathrm{A_{33}} \\
    \end{bmatrix}
 \cdot
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \Delta\mathrm{uC1} \\[0.5em]
  \Delta\mathrm{iL} \\[0.5em]
  \Delta\mathrm{uC2} \\
 \end{bmatrix}
 +
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \mathrm{B_{11}} & \mathrm{B_{12}} & \mathrm{B_{13}} \\[0.5em]
        \mathrm{B_{21}} & \mathrm{B_{22}} & \mathrm{B_{23}} \\[0.5em]
        \mathrm{B_{31}} & \mathrm{B_{32}} & \mathrm{B_{33}} \\
 \end{bmatrix}
 \cdot
 \begin{bmatrix}
        \Delta\mathrm{Uin} \\[0.5em]
  \Delta\mathrm{Uac} \\[0.5em]
  \Delta\delta
 \end{bmatrix} 
\end{align}\$

As you can see, my Buck/Boost-Converter contains 3 State-Variables.
I did an Impulse-Response Analysis in PLECS (Simulation) to obtain the Bode-Plot from the perturbation in an equilibrium Point.

After that I used \$\mathrm{tfest}()\$ in Matlab to generate \$G(s)\$ for the Bode-Plot.

I have following Transfer-Functions:

For \$\mathrm{uC1}\$: \$ \dfrac{\mathrm{uC1}}{\mathrm{Uin}}(s),\dfrac{\mathrm{uC1}}{\mathrm{Uac}}(s),\dfrac{\mathrm{uC1}}{\delta}(s) \$

For \$\mathrm{iL}\$: \$ \dfrac{\mathrm{iL}}{\mathrm{Uin}}(s),\dfrac{\mathrm{iL}}{\mathrm{Uac}}(s),\dfrac{\mathrm{iL}}{\delta}(s) \$

For \$\mathrm{uC2}\$: \$ \dfrac{\mathrm{uC2}}{\mathrm{Uin}}(s),\dfrac{\mathrm{uC2}}{\mathrm{Uac}}(s),\dfrac{\mathrm{uC1}}{\delta}(s) \$

and want to convert them into an State-Space-Model.
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

In Matlab, you could just apply `ss()` to your matrix of Transfer-functions and that should do it.

For example,

```
G = [tf(rand(1,1),rand(1,2)), tf(rand(1,1),rand(1,2)); tf(rand(1,1),rand(1,2)), tf(rand(1,1),rand(1,2))];

ss(G)
```

and you get

```
G

Transfer function 'G' from input 'u1' to output ...

           0.1182
 y1:  -----------------
      0.1398 s + 0.1585

           0.2366
 y2:  -----------------
      0.4479 s + 0.7206

Transfer function 'G' from input 'u2' to output ...

           0.8437
 y1:  ----------------
      0.446 s + 0.4288

           0.8192
 y2:  -----------------
      0.7782 s + 0.0429


ss(G)

ans.a =
               x1          x2          x3          x4
   x1   3.781e-17   5.228e-17  -6.661e-16     0.08869
   x2   6.074e-16   3.508e-16        1.09   9.021e-17
   x3           0          -1      -2.095   9.714e-17
   x4          -1  -5.551e-16           0      -1.664

ans.b =
             u1        u2
   x1  -0.01015   -0.5903
   x2   -0.5066    -1.337
   x3     0.527      1.18
   x4    0.1841    0.3669

ans.c =
          x1     x2     x3     x4
   y1      0      0  1.604      0
   y2      0      0      0  2.869

ans.d =
       u1  u2
   y1   0   0
   y2   0   0

Continuous-time model.
```

Comment: I already thought of that and tried it out, but i dont know how to arrange the tf-Matrix to achieve exactly that State-Space form like i need it. I also got an very high-order state-space Model instead of an 3x3.. maybe you can provide an example?

Comment: Ok, but shouldn’t be the A-Matrix an 2x2 and B also? Assuming 2 State-Variables and 2 Inputs?

Comment: No, that is not how it goes. If we have \$p\$ output and \$m\$ inputs we can say \$C \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times n}\$ and \$B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}\$. But the dimentions of \$A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}\$ are not so easy to determine, it depends on how many (different valued) poles the transfer functions have and how each inputs affects each state. I suggest you look for it online or ask a new question just on how to write MIMO Transfer function matrices into state space equations.

Comment: I there any reason you have not up voted or closed this question? is this not the answer to your question? Any problems/suggestions?